# SQL Server - Create multiple rows from a single record based on time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a query that returns a separate row for each month from a table that has records with a start month and an end month. E.G. If the record has a start month of January 2012 and an end month of March 2012, I would want to return three rows – Jan 2012, Feb 2012 & March 2012. The actual gap between the start and end month could span several years and the number of rows that need to be returned will vary from record to record. The actual purpose is to split the total cost into a cost per month

Something like:

Record:

```
Value  Start Month  End Month
 30     Jan 2012     March 2012
```

Query Returns

```
Value  Month
 10    Jan 2012
 10    Feb 2012
 10    March 2012
```

Have been searching for hours – can anybody help me!!! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table of integers you can join on the date part to the [table of integers](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) which will give you the month range. Another join to a table of month descriptions will get you your labels back. To Get the split cost you will need to work out the number of rows in the between and divide the cost (assuming its a straight split.

```
    select 
    bb.integer as MonthDesc,
cc.MonthDescription,
aa.MyCost / datediff(mm,mydatefield, mydatefield2)
    datepart(yy, mydatefield)
    from dbo.tblMyTableofFacts aa
    inner join dbo.tblMyTableOfInters bb
    on bb.integer between datepart(mm,mydatefield) and datepart(mm,mydatefield2)

inner join dbo.tblMyTableOfMonths cc
on bb.Integer = cc.MonthNumber
```

Comment: Fantastic - exactly what I needed - worked a treat - Many thanks